# ASP.NET Display data in one GridView from multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to Display the following code in a GridView and I don't know how to do or I don't know if I'am doing right.... 
Please help!

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDb"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand((@"select e.FirstName,
                        count(case when v.VacationDates = @day1 THEN 1 END),
                        count(case when v.VacationDates = @day2 THEN 1 END),
                        count(case when v.VacationDates = @day3 THEN 1 END),
                        count(case when v.VacationDates = @day4 THEN 1 END),
                        count(case when v.VacationDates = @day5 THEN 1 END),
                        count(case when v.VacationDates = @day6 THEN 1 END),
                        count(case when v.VacationDates = @day7 THEN 1 END)
                        from Employee e

                        left join Vacation v
                        on e.EmployeeId = v.EmployeeId
                        group by e.FirstName"), connection) ;

 if (Calendar1.SelectedDates.Count > 6)
                {
                    cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day1", Calendar1.SelectedDates[0].ToShortDateString());
                    cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day2", Calendar1.SelectedDates[1].ToShortDateString());
                    cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day3", Calendar1.SelectedDates[2].ToShortDateString());
                    cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day4", Calendar1.SelectedDates[3].ToShortDateString());
                    cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day5", Calendar1.SelectedDates[4].ToShortDateString());
                    cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day6", Calendar1.SelectedDates[5].ToShortDateString());
                    cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day7", Calendar1.SelectedDates[6].ToShortDateString());




                        connection.Open();

                        GridView12.DataSource = cmd5.ExecuteReader();
                        GridView12.DataBind();


               }
}
```

Calendar1.SelectedDates[0].ToShortDateString()
Calendar1.SelectedDates[1].ToShortDateString().... is a value geting from Calendar. Thank you in advacnce!

Comment: Is this an SQL question or a GridView question? Are you getting data from the database but not into a GridView or not getting any data from the database at all?

Comment: @VDWWD thank you for your response. It's GridView question and data from database offcourse. I get errors like "index was out of range. must be nonnegative and less than the size of the collection"  on those rows  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day2", Calendar1.SelectedDates[1].ToShortDateString());

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it seems correct, but you have one issue that you need to handle and it's that if the user hasn't selected the seven (7) dates required for your query the program will throw a 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'. What i suggest you in order to avoid the 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' exception is to include:

```
if (Calendar1.SelectedDates.Count > 6)
{
(your code)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I did and I don't get error message anymore but my GridView do not show. I can't se The GridView. I have edited my code. Thank you again!